# I am trying to place buttons at the bottom of the screen with React-Native and I really struggle to understand how to do it properly with flex support

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to build up an application with React-Native and I need to place two buttons next to each other at the bottom of the screen. So far I wrote this code:

```
    render() {
        const { subtitle } = this.state;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ActionBar onBackAction={this.backActionHandler} isBackAvailable />
                <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
                    <Text>{subtitle}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
                    <Button title="BTN #1" />
                    <Button title="BTN #2" />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

With these styles:

```
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'space-between'
        },
        contentContainer: {
            flex: 1,
            flexGrow: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'purple'
        },
        buttonsContainer: {
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            marginBottom: 40,
            backgroundColor: 'red'
        }
    });
```

And this is the result so far...

[image: the result]

And this is what I want to achieve:

[image: the result]

Could anybody point me where is my mistake? If this is important, the whole screen above is nested in another View with just `flex: 1` property. I am trying to understand this flex conception, but I can't manage to do that.

Comment: both `contentContainer` and `buttonsContainer` has `flex:1` then they will have an equal height! try increasing flex number for `contentContainer` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `flex` to `0` for `buttonsContainer` style. When you put `flex: 1` to both `buttonsContainer` and `contentContainer`, the available space is distributed among these two containers. But as per your requirement, `contentContainer` should take all the available space. So, setting `contentContainer` to `flex: 1` is correct. To get the desired result set `flex: 0` to `buttonsContainer` or you can avoid the `flex` property for `buttonsContainer`.

Read more about flex [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).
Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when I do that I can't vertically center buttons inside `buttonsContainer`.

Comment: For vertical center, you can use `alignItems: 'center'` with `buttonsContainer`.

Comment: Thanks buddy, now I see my mistakes! Have a nice day :)